What does "mdw" in "mdwtab"/"mdwlist/mdwmath" packages mean?
I am just learning the enumitem package and I just encountered the package name mdwlist on the introductory page. I wonder what the letters mdw (which is also present in several other packages like mdwtab, mdwmath, or the mdwtools bundle, of course) stand for here and start searching, just ending with no results. So could anyone tell me what the three letters mdw mean here ?
I know maybe this is not a question so important in terms of the programming or technology, but the unawareness of the meaning of abbreviations of a short string of letters in some package names is just too troublesome for an obsessive in this regard just like me...
P.S. I'm not a native speaker of English but I wonder if this type of problem also annoys some of you who speak English as their mother tongue...
Many thanks ahead to whoever pays a little attention to this trivial question !

The name of the author is Mark Wooding.

And I guess his middle name starts with D.

Thanks for comments of you two ! Yeah I the author's name is the very possibility, which I also thought of. And thanks a lot to egreg for your proposition as reagrds how to explain the middle "d" in it...

From mdwlist.dtx
% \begin{meta-comment}
%
% $Id: mdwlist.dtx,v 1.1 1996/11/19 20:52:26 mdw Exp $
%
% Various list-related things
%
% (c) 1996 Mark Wooding
%
%----- Revision history -----------------------------------------------------
%
% $Log: mdwlist.dtx,v $
% Revision 1.1  1996/11/19 20:52:26  mdw
% Initial revision
%
%
% \end{meta-comment}

The author, Mark Wooding, uses a mdw abbreviation throughout (likely D is the initial of a middle name).
I'd avoid mdw... packages, because they have been umaintaned for almost 30 years. Some use syntax, but be aware it has some shortcomings.
